# FCM push notification error in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in }
    )

    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
    FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self //ERROR THIS LINE

}
else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
```

Getting error when set the delegate to self.
"FIRMessing has no member remoteMessageDelegate"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Google documentation is out of date.

Please run the following commands in your terminal:

```
pod repo update
```

Then go to your project folder and run

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate{
}

//MARK: FIRMessaging Delegate
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage){  
}
```